# display error message in popup

Tags: php, codeigniter

Iam displaying pop up for login form in home page.when i given wrong email/password pop up gone , when i open pop up error message displayed in popup.

my home-page

```
           <div class="modal fade" id="signin" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog ">   
  <div class="modal-content"> 

    <div class="modal-header"> 
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title"> Sign in </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">  
        <div class="tabiib-popbox">
         <div class="col-xs-12"> 

      <ul class="nav nav-tabs poptabs">

        <li class="tab signin"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home"> Sign In</a></li>

      </ul>
     <div class="tabiib-signin">
     <div class="tab-content">
     <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in">
          <form class="pop-l" action="<?php echo base_url('LoginPopup');?>"    method="post" name="signin" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('Message');?>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Mobile Number / Email ID </label>
        <input type="text" name="emailMobileNumber" class="form-control" id="email">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">   
        <label for="pwd">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
      </div>


      <div class="pop-b text-center"> 
      <input type="submit" class="btn popbtn" value="Sign In">        
       </div>   
    </form> 
</div>
```

Controller:

```
       public function    LoginPopup() {        

        $postDatas = $this->input->post();

        $postData = str_replace (" ", "", $postDatas);
        $postData['userType'] = 3;
        $this->load->model('modelname');
        $response = $this->modelname->login($postData);

        if(isset($response['success_message'])) {

            $user = set_user_session($response['data']);
            $this->session->set_userdata('userdata', $user);
            $sessionData = $this->session->userdata('userdata');
            $this->session->set_userdata('Login',1);
            $details = getDet($sessionData['userRef']);
            $this->session->set_userdata('Details', $details);

            redirect('');  
            }else{

            $msg = '<div class="alert alert-danger"><i class="fa fa-ban"></i>';
            $msg .= 'Mobile Number/Email or Password does not match';
            $msg .= '</div>';
            $mesg=$this->session->set_flashdata('Message', $msg);           

        redirect('');   

            }
    }
```

But i need popup will stay and display error message in that pop up  until we given correct email/password popup will not hide

Comment: Can you clarify your question?

Comment: error message displaying in popup correctly when i given wrong credentials but pop up gone , i need popup to stay in home page and display error message in popup

Comment: What do you mean pop-up gone? Does it appear after redirecting from login pop-up?

Comment: pop up dont gone until i given correct credentials i need @Alex

Comment: but that makes sense... if you have an error it adds to flash and then you redirect to your page where the flash message is displayed. if you keep entering the wrong data and submitting the form the logic stays the same: form (wrong creds) > post > error > flash message... If you want it to disappear after some time then you have to use javascript for that. Put the message in a div in your view and set a timeout on the div to fade or something.

Comment: can you please provide example @Alex

Comment: there are plenty on stack and elsewhere. if this is truly your goal then you should change your tags and revise your question for clarity (something i suggest you do anyways as its very confusing) because your question sounds like you are having a flash message issue whereas you are actually need js help (so it seems)

Comment: what was confusing in my question, just  after form submit, message is showing correctly but pop up disappearing when i click again on pop up error message showing in pop up but i want until  given correct credentials only pop up will disappear

Comment: i'm sorry but that is confusing. perhaps use pictures or something.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is that, use ajax to submit form . But if u don't want to use ajax then at first, if error comes, write error message in session. then after redirection in home page, check session if error is or not. If error is there then show the model with error message. But it's not a flash message remember it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Replace

```
$msg = '<div class="alert alert-danger"><i class="fa fa-ban"></i>';
$msg .= 'Mobile Number/Email or Password does not match';
$msg .= '</div>';
$mesg=$this->session->set_flashdata('Message', $msg);           
redirect('');
```

to

```
$data['msg'] = '<div class="alert alert-danger"><i class="fa fa-ban"></i>';
$data['msg'] .= 'Mobile Number/Email or Password does not match';
$data['msg'] .= '</div>';
$this->load->view('LoginView',$data); #LoginView  is a view where you login form is present
```

Add some lines in LoginView

```
if(uri_string()=="/LoginPopup")
{
echo $msg;
}
```

Comment: Problemis in your action url try this in view `action="<?php echo base_url('**ControllerName**/LoginPopup');?>"` Must give Controller Name

Comment: i wrote in routes $route["patientLoginPopup"] = "RegisterController/patientLoginPopup"; so that  why i didnt given controller name

Comment: Remove this condition in view `if(uri_string()=="/LoginPopup"),`

Comment: message is showing correctly but pop up disappearing

Comment: Still I dont understand what you are try to doing. can you add screen shot of problem and css of popup

Answer (score -1):

If you use redirect('') then definitely page will be redirected and popup will not be shown. Use ajax for form submission it will solve your problem.

Comment: how to do it in that page

Comment: $.ajax({

  type        : 'POST',
  url         : url,
  data : {data : data},
  dataType    : 'json',
  success     : function(response){
   if(response.status=='success')
   {

   $("#modelid").modal("hide");
   
   }
   if(response.status=='error')
   {
    $("#messagedivinpopupmodal").html(response.content');
   }
  }

 });

Comment: He's setting a flash message

Comment: it is not necessary to set a flash message , there are alternatives to show messages. so, he should change his approach.

Comment: Then you should say that instead "if you use redirect it won't work" because that's not true, and although his method isn't modern, it should work and I think that's what he wants to address.

Comment: why down vote? i don't think it was necessary to do so.